# How i can use two optional object in c# when one of them is required?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i got the information on page through query-string and i validate them through the data annotation feature.

on the page i got the pId or eId. the one of them in every situation the one of them are always found how i can validate them in MVC.

can someone tell me how i can do this in c# asp.net mvc through the data-annotation.

are this works if  i do it

```
 public string pId 
        {
            get;
            set
            {
                eId= value;
                pId = value;
            }
        }

        public string eId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

Comment: This will give you a StackOverflowException - setting pId in the setter will call the setter again and so on..

Comment: can someone do it for me or rewrite it how i can validate it when one of them is required in every condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the situation is that you *allways* need either pId set OR eId - one of them might be null/empty but never both. And you want to do this with some kind of DataAnotation instead of some other kind of validation.

I don't know if this is possible directly with what is there but I doubt.
But you can implement your own [custom validation attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute.aspx) (as Phil shows how in [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx) great blog-post):

I guess to work this with this you need to extract your EId/PId into a Id-class because the object to validate will be value of your annotated field.

Another way would be to implement the [IValidatableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx)-Interface (see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) blog post)

Here is a example for your type

```
class MyClass : IValidatableObject
{
   public string EId {get;set;}
   public string PId {get;set;}

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext vC)
   {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EId) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(PId))
         yield return new ValidationResult("one of EId or PId must be set!", new []{ "EId", "PId" });
   }

}
```

And finaly here is a nice [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405.aspx) on MSDN: